# Telnet Post request not working with a simple php script on the server

Tags: php, http, telnet

I am learning about the Post request, and for this I have written a basic PHP script which is being called through a telnet post request. However, when I run it I am not getting the expected output.

## The PHP code is as follows (saved as p.php):

```
<?php 
    foreach($_REQUEST as $key=>$value)
    {
            echo "$key:$value<br>\n";
    }
?>
```

## Then from the terminal I run telnet as follows:

```
telnet  example.com 80
post /p.php http/1.0
host: example.com
connection:close
content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
content-length:16

name=jim&age=20
```

## The output is as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 24 Dec 2014 13:04:38 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.1.6
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Connection closed by foreign host.
```

---

So as you can see, it shows no output (echo of the post request). Looking forward to your help and advice.

Comment: two things hit my eye: a) the extra line between content-length and name=jim, dont do that, and b) try to output $_POST instead of $_REQUEST

Comment: Also is there a reason you are using `telnet` instead of `curl`... seems like `curl` would be a better choice for delving in to this.

Comment: @TuncayGöncüoğlu  a) without the extra space I receive an error: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
Request header field is missing ':' separator.<br />
<pre>
name=tom&amp;age=14</pre>
</p>
<hr> .......

Comment: @TuncayGöncüoğlu also tried changing the Receive to Post, and have the same issues as above.  I was using Telnet, as this is just the example I am working through for the moment. So want to try and recreate the same results.

Comment: I'm not family with curl yet, as just learning this for now. But will try looking into that.